# Conditional Query for Employee Training Analysis Query

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements

I need to run training queries that return results for questions like the following: "Who has completed this training, but not that training?"

In the simplified table below, I would like to know which employee has completed training_id 1 (as indicated by a date in the completed_date field), but has not finished training_id 7.

```
+-------------+-------------+----------------+
| emp_id      | training_id | completed_date |
+-------------+-------------+----------------+
| 1           | 1           | 2010-04-02     |
+-------------+-------------+----------------+
| 1           | 7           | Null           |
+-------------+-------------+----------------+
| 2           | 1           | Null           |
+-------------+-------------+----------------+
| 2           | 7           | Null           |
+-------------+-------------+----------------+
```

Desired result would be emp_id 1 and we'd like to return his/her completed training and non-completed training per the query parameters:

```
+-------------+-------------+----------------+
| emp_id      | training_id | completed_date |
+-------------+-------------+----------------+
| 1           | 1           | 2010-04-02     |
+-------------+-------------+----------------+
| 1           | 7           | Null           |
+-------------+-------------+----------------+
```

I can't figure out how to do this with a regular query because it seems to need IF logic. Ex: Return rows where this one training is complete and return rows where this second training is not complete BUT ONLY if the first training is complete.

How do I express something like that in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an EXISTS clause

```
SELECT t.*
FROM training t

# which employee has completed training_id 1
WHERE t.training_id = 1 and t.completed_date is not null

#but has not finished training_id 7.
AND NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT * FROM training t2
     where t2.emp_id=t.emp_id
       and t2.training_id = 7
       and t2.completed_date is not null)
```

If you wanted to test something more complex, like `completed (4,5,6) but not (1,9)`, then you can use counts:

```
SELECT t.emp_id
FROM training t
WHERE t.training_id in (4,5,6) and t.completed_date is not null
group by t.emp_id
having count(distinct emp_id) = 3

AND NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT * FROM training t2
     where t2.emp_id=t.emp_id
       and t2.training_id in (1,9)
       and t2.completed_date is not null)
```

And finally if you need the full employee training record

```
SELECT e.*
FROM
(
    SELECT t.emp_id
    FROM training t
    WHERE t.training_id in (4,5,6) and t.completed_date is not null
    group by t.emp_id
    having count(distinct emp_id) = 3

    AND NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT * FROM training t2
         where t2.emp_id=t.emp_id
           and t2.training_id in (1,9)
           and t2.completed_date is not null)
) search
inner join training e on e.emp_id = search.emp_id
order by e.emp_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from training where emp_id in
(
  select distinct emp_id from training where completed_Date is not null
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a self-join on this table ("pretend it is two identical tables and join them"):

```
SELECT t1.emp_id, t1.training_id, t1.completed_date,
       t2.training_id, t2.completed_date
    FROM training AS t1 /* the aliases are needed for the self-join */
    JOIN training AS t2
        ON t1.emp_id = t2.emp_id
        AND t2.training_id = 7 /* second training  ID */
    WHERE t1.training_id = 1 /* first training ID */
```

That should give you a result like this:

```
t1.emp_id | t1.training_id | t1.completed_date | t2.training_id | t2.completed_date
 1            1               2010-04-02          7                NULL
 2            1               NULL                7                NULL
```

You can then further limit the WHERE query, e.g. with

```
         AND t1.completed_date IS NOT NULL
         AND t2.completed_date IS NULL
```

which will give you the set that you want - training 1 completed, training 7 not.